# Lines do not appear between the columns of my grid and widen the gird

Tags: css, razor, webmatrix, webgrid

My grid works but, I would like to display lines between the grid columns.  I have tried making several changes but, nothing happens.  I would also like to widen the grid because the words on some of my columns are wrapping.

Below is the code for the grid:

```
<div id="Divgrid">
     @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserId, "admin") && (AdminData.Any())){
              @AdminGrid.GetHtml(
              tableStyle: "grid",
              headerStyle: "grid-header",
              footerStyle: "grid-footer",
              alternatingRowStyle: "grid-alternating-row",
              selectedRowStyle: "grid-selected-row",
              rowStyle: "grid-row-style",
              columns: AdminGrid.Columns(
                   AdminGrid.Column(header:"", format:@<a href="View/@item.Id">View</a>),
                   AdminGrid.Column(header:"", format:@<a href="Treatment/@item.Id">Treatment</a>),
                   AdminGrid.Column("Name", format:@<text>@item.ClientName</text>),
                   AdminGrid.Column("Date", format:@<text>@item.SubmitDate</text>))) }
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserId, "user") && (data.Any())) {
                 @grid.GetHtml(
                 tableStyle: "grid",
                 headerStyle: "grid-header",
                 footerStyle: "grid-footer",
                 alternatingRowStyle: "grid-alternating-row",
                 selectedRowStyle: "grid-selected-row",
                 rowStyle: "grid-row-style",
                 columns: grid.Columns(
                      grid.Column(header:"", format:@<a href="View/@item.Id">View</a>),
                      grid.Column(header:"", format:@<a href="Treatment/@item.Id">Treatment</a>),
                      grid.Column("Name", format:@<text>@item.ClientName</text>),
                      grid.Column("Date", format:@<text>@item.SubmitDate</text>))) }                    

   </div>
```

Here is the code in my Site.css:

```
.grid
   {
       margin: 4px; 
       width: 960px;   
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
   }

   .grid a
   {
       color: #000;
   }

    .grid-row-style td
    {
        text-align:left;
        border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .grid-header th
    {
        text-align:left;
        border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;         

        padding-right:20px;
        padding-left:20px;
    }
    .grid-alternating-row td
    {
        text-align:left;
        border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
        padding: 5px;
    }
   .grid-header
   {
       padding: 6px 5px;
       text-align: left;
       border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
       background-color: #e8eef4;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #3966A2;
       height: 40px;

       border-top: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
       border-left: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
       border-right: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
   }

   .grid-footer
   {
       padding: 6px 5px;
       text-align: center;
       background-color: #e8eef4;
       border-top: 2px solid #3966A2;
       height: 30px;

       border-bottom: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
       border-left: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
       border-right: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
   }

   .grid-alternating-row
   {
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #d2d2d2;

      border-left: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
      border-right: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
  }
    .grid-row-style
   {
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
      padding: 5px;

      border-left: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
      border-right: 2px solid #D6E8FF;
   }

   .grid-selected-row
   {
       font-weight: bold;
   }
```

Comment: maybe you should provide  codepen or fiddle that works so we have the real html structure to wich CSS is applied or build a snippet here :) (adding links to your libraries

Comment: Nevermind I got it.  I added width:auto to my .grid-row-style td and .grid-alternating-row td.